# error while printing the predicted value in multiple linear regression

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, olsmultiplelinearregression

```
from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
x = np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
y = np.asanyarray(train[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
regr.fit (x, y)
# The coefficients
print ('Coefficients: ', regr.coef_)
x1 = np.asanyarray(test[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
y1 = np.asanyarray(test[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
xy = regr.predict(y1)
print(xy) // an error is generating while printing this (valueError)
```

this worked in simple linear regression but here is not working in multiple-linear-regression

Answer (score 1):

`regr.predict` expects the same shape of `x`.

Furthermore, when you want to predict something, it should be based on some input, not output.

So, `xy = regr.predict(y1)` is wrong.

You should try `xy = regr.predict(x1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works (but in fact, it is not correct) in simple regression in that you provide a 1D array to `regr.predict`. As mentionned, this should be `regr.predict(x1)` instread of `regr.predict(y1)`, since you are trying to predict `y1` **from** `x1`. The algorithm does not "distinguish" between `x1` and `y1` in simple regression because they are both 1D arrays, so it does not raise an error.

However in multiple regression, you fit an equation on a 2D or 3D or...N-dimensional `x` array. So, when you run `regr.predict(y1)`, it raises an error because you are trying to predict with the 1D `y1` array.

Just replace `regr.predict(y1)` by `regr.predict(x1)` and it will work both for simple and multiple regrerssion.